# Override Profile2 with account fields and values

Tags: theming

I have created a new Profile Type with Profile2 module. Now I want to override it, importing three existing fields from my original Account (First Name, Last Name, Email) with their own values (that have already been set in the registration process).

I think I must try copying `profile2.tpl.php` on my theme page, but no changes seems to happen. Any idea about how to do it?

Comment: I am not clear with your requirement. Why do you mention using profile2.tpl.php?..You just want this for a display purpose or you want those fields in the profile you created to actually hold the corresponding values from user registration form?

Comment: I need to repeat those fields in my new Profile Type, so the user can see and change their values, if they want.

Answer (score 0):

Profile2 modules gives profile entity apart from we have in default as user.I am not putting the codes , but here is my idea,

1. manually add those three fields to the profile you have created.
2. loop through all users, load their profile, I guess you can use [profile2_load_by_user()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!profile2!profile2.module/function/profile2_load_by_user/7) to load the profile inside the loop
3. Check if you are getting the added fields in the loaded profile object.
4. Map the fields on user entity to profile entity.
5. save the profile using profile2_save() 5.
6. Delete the fields from user entity, once you ensure mapping is in the way you want.

**NOTE:** function listed may need a replacement,as I have not tested the workflow.